# Item disappears after updating in Podio

Tags: c#, podio

I am connecting to Podio from out c# application and I am having strange issue:

1 - read item from Podio using this code:

```
var item = podio.ItemService.GetItem(itemId);
```

I receive back the item I wanted. So far OK.

2 - update the item (following the Podio tutorial):

```
var item = new Item();
item.ItemId = itemId;
item.Field<TextItemField>("company").Value = "Test Company";
podio.ItemService.UpdateItem(item, spaceId);
```

The item is correctly updated and I can see the changes on the web.

3 - read the same item again

The same method as on the first step now returns null.

The item is visible on the web, I can even read the json from the "sandbox" on the documentation pages (https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/get-item-22360).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be sure you are using latest Podio libs. There was an issue with `item_revision_id` that is fixed in Podio 1.5.8 and Podio.Async 2.0.0 NuGet packages.

Comment: Hi Pavlo. Thanks for the answe, that was indeed the issue.